# Apagar registro em várias tabelas no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho várias tabelas com um mesmo campo `versao`. Gostaria de apagar simultaneamente em todas as tabelas todos os registros que contenham o campo `versao` com um mesmo valor 'XYZ'.

Tentei

```
DELETE FROM `t1`, `t2`, `t3` WHERE `versao` = 'XYZ';
```

mas não rolou...

O que estou fazendo de errado?
Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: Tentou fazer três comandos separados?

Comment: Usando metadados https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/clear-all-tables-with-one-delete

Comment: tudo o q não quero é fazer mais de um comando.

Comment: Se não quiser fazer varios DELETEs pode usar forekeys e no after delete voce usa triggers e deleta as tabelas relacionadas, uma vez feita no banco pode usar qualquer front-end que o banco fará o mesmo

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe oficial é:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name [[AS] tbl_alias]
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

No seu caso após o FROM você colocou mais de uma tabela.
Uma solução seria:

```
DELETE FROM `t1` WHERE `versao` = 'XYZ';
DELETE FROM `t2` WHERE `versao` = 'XYZ';
DELETE FROM `t3` WHERE `versao` = 'XYZ';
```

Comment: Sim, sim. Mas achei casos apagando em mais de uma tabela... Usando INNER JOIN. Porém eram situações ainda mais complexas que envolviam relacionamento, o que não é meu caso. Meu caso é mais simples (acho)...

Comment: É justamente o que quero evitar.

Comment: olha isso : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598791/sql-delete-with-inner-join

Comment: Se não quiser fazer varios DELETEs pode usar forekeys e no after delete voce usa triggers e deleta as tabelas relacionadas, uma vez feita no banco pode usar qualquer front-end que o banco fará o mesmo